# Could there be a Wikipedia Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, wikipedia

Sometimes I'm editing on Wikipedia. Since I'm very new, I still have a lot of problems. It's hard for my to find information about editing on Wikipedia.

I would like a Wikipedia Stack Exchange site, where I can get help with all my editor problems. Like, when I have problems with creating a table, problems creating a plot, etc.

Or when I have problems with understanding the policy, I would like to get help. Especially since the Wikipedia guidelines are multitudinous, hardly comprehensible and understandable.

Comment: Yes please! I would like this a lot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### I would like a Wikipedia Stackexchange

> where I can get help with all my editor problems.

Have you looked at [Wikipedia Help:Contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents)? - it is quite extensive.

If that doesn't answer your questions you could try asking on http://webapps.stackexchange.com, they have a [wikipedia](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikipedia) tag.

If you want a new Stack Exchange site you need to propose one on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/):

> Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone, where users come together to build new Q&A sites. New site ideas are proposed, discussed, and the best go on to beta. See the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

From the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **How do I start a new site?**
>
> If your area of expertise doesn't already have a Stack Exchange site, propose it! Stack Exchange sites are free to create and free to use. All we ask is that you have an enthusiastic, committed group of expert users who check in regularly, asking and answering questions.
>
> The creation of Stack Exchange sites is a community-driven process. That does not mean the majority of Area 51 users have to love your site idea. It simply means you have to recruit a community of users large enough so that questions get good answers quickly. Reach out to other experts to build support for your site; bloggers, enthusiasts, and support groups can all benefit from a world-class, canonical collection of expert answers to the hardest questions.

Comment: And then Wikipedia Stack Exchange gets a Wikipedia article which garnishes questions on Wikipedia Stack Exchange, and the internet explodes.

Comment: @PyRulez Recursion is a great thing, until it destroys the world.

Comment: @hBy2Py This all started with a site called Stack Overflow, after all. A little runaway recursion never hurt anybody.

Comment: @PyRulez No, it does not explode, no worries. Because it only grows linearly, not exponentially. Pointing it out because there are things that can, and actually did explode and bring the internet down.

Comment: @JLRishe You are right indeed. A runaway recursion does not hurt anybody. Because there is a large constant time delay per iteration, and it is linear. One could actually repeat something with one second delay indefinitely, because there is more than one computer added to the internet per second. (I would actually like seeing the runaway recursion, it's just worth it as a piece of art)