# Wikipedia community

Tags: discussion, wikipedia

Has a *Ask Wikipedia* community ever been considered to discuss Wikipedia's rules and policy outside of Wikipedia? If yes where can we find the discussions? It already exists on Wikipedia, of course. It's not that it's not well done in Wikipedia. It's just that any approach to encourage other people to provide their expertise about Wikipedia might be a good idea. Anyway, the question is where it has been discussed, if it has been.

Note added: It's not a proposal. In fact, reflecting more about my feelings and intentions behind that question, I was not seriously considering to make a proposal and that's why I did not even mentioned it in Wikipedia. I simply don't see myself making that proposal. It is just that I felt that it would be interesting to know if that was discussed seriously enough that it unfolded up to here. In that context, sorry, but the down votes are a  weird community habit.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better hosted by [Wikipedia themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contact_us)?

Comment: It already exists on Wikipedia, of course. But the organization on Stack exchange is completely different. It would create a different perspective, perhaps with different people.

Comment: Down votes are not informative here. It is simpler to say no it has not been considered if that is the intention. Otherwise, please express yourself more clearly.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Most likely people think this is a) poorly researched and/or b) disagree that it's a good idea. You've not said why Wikipedia's discussion avenues are insufficient, or what having an additional site here would achieve since most people actually contributing to Wikipedia would likely be unaware of it if it existed and would presumably be more comfortable using the tool they already know i.e. Wikipedia.

Comment: There is [a deleted proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/edit-wiki). Is it visible to 10'ers?

Comment: Longson, yes, but it was not a proposal. On the contrary, I ask the question because I start my research on the issue. Yes, I haven't done a research and I ask a question to know if it has been discussed. It's a natural starting point for that research.

Comment: Well I would have started my research on Wikipedia if I planned to ask such a question. The people there could presumably tell me whether they would get behind such a proposal or not. Then when I came here I'd be able to say. I have so many hundreds of people that want this based on my research... The following community features are missing on Wikipedia's site and they are hard to fix because...

Comment: Thanks P.Mort. This is it. This is the kind of answer the question is calling for. Unfortunately, I cannot see the discussion, but it is still useful information.

Comment: It's very subjective where it's better to start. For an actual proposal, yes, one must have checked the interest in Wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not really sure how such a site can work on Stack Exchange, which is mainly a strictly objective Q&A site, not a discussion site (Meta sites, and especially Meta Stack Exchange are exceptions). Like, what kind of questions would be asked and answered?

Comment: please do not edit meta commentary in the question body or title.

Comment: There is a question and answer site about Wikipedia on Wikipedia; it's called the Teahouse.

Comment: I would not have asked the question in the Teahouse, because it can easily be misinterpreted as something in competition. It leads to controversial discussions and I would not have taken a chance to compromise how I am perceived  in Wikipedia, even though the idea was entirely positive in my mind.

Comment: Related: [Wikipedia Stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277895)

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that's very much something that is 'best' mooted on wikipedia, for their community to find that 'our' way of doing things works better then their way - through talk pages and other tools (Our current VP of community used to work there and would have better insight on the workflow there.)

Without that though - It *should* and *would* fail, and is no different from folk trying to set SE policy via twitter. Its still an external platform.

Rules and policy are always best discussed and formulated *within* a community - by its users, for its users and in consultation with them in a shared space.

Comment: It's not better. It would be a complement.  I see that people interpreted my question as if it was a proposal. I did not want to go into this. I just wanted to know if has been discussed, nothing more. Very simple question.

Comment: Fundamentally - that discussion *needs* to start on wikipedia

Comment: Please put yourselves in my position. It's just a simple question. Was it discussed here? The reason why I decided to ask this here before inquiring about the interest in Wikipedia is not important. Perhaps I wanted to see if it was even a possibility before starting a discussion in Wikipedia. The reason should not be your concern. There was nothing wrong with the question in itself and that should be your only concern. The down votes as a way to answer this simple question is very bad. I am glad to have deleted my profile.

Answer (score 5):

There's no Stack Exchange site to "discuss Wikipedia's rules and policy". I'd expect a site proposed for this on Area 51 to be closed. This type of discussion is something that needs to happen on Wikipedia itself, where all the interested parties are. Similarly, discussion of Stack Exchange rules and policies happens here, not Wikipedia.

Some sites accept certain questions about Wikipedia, but — again — usually not on their rules or policies. Here are some examples:

Writing:

- [Is Wikipedia Trustworthy?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/32135/34330)
- [How do we write a good edit on Wikipedia?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43210/34330)

Web Apps:

- [How can I find out who wrote a certain section of an article in Wikipedia?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/367/197614)
- [How does Wikipedia prevent spamming?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22625/197614)

Wikipedia is such a broad-reaching site that it's hard to list all the SE sites that might possibly accept some question about it. Even Meta has the occasional Wikipedia question or two: [What are the requirements for using Stack Overflow content on Wikipedia?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110466/323179)